# How to get Spring @ControllerAdvice work with other custom Spring @Aspect?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I have a custom logger using `@Aspect` that I wish it always run at the last so that no matter what response returned from the controller, it will be logged to the database (so I put an `@Order(1)` on this aspect).  And I have also written an error handler using `@ControllerAdvice` that handles all unexpected exceptions and returns `500` with a custom response body, and I want this to be logged by the logger as well so I put an `@Order(2)` on it, however looks like putting `@Order` annotation does not arrange the orders between Spring Aspect and Spring ControllerAdvice, so how do I let my error handler always run before the logger? (of course, without turning my error handler to another Spring Aspect)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been looking and debugging for your main problem. I didn't find the answer of your question about `@Order`, but I'll share with you my thinking (second part of this post)

### Have you considered using `Interceptor`?

They provide way to log actions before you enter the controller, and after the `@ControllerAdvice` is executed, if there is one.

```
@Component
public class WebInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        logger.error("WebInterceptor prehandle is now logged");
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        logger.error("WebInterceptor after completion is now logged");
        super.afterCompletion(request, response, handler, ex);
    }
}
```

To activate this Interceptor, you need to create a new `@Configuration` class, implementing `WebMvcConfigurer`:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private WebInterceptor webInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(webInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/user");
    }
}
```

I've created a simple `Controller` and `ControllerAdvice` for the test:

```
@RestController
public class WebController {
    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String user() {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("my bad");
    }
}


@RestControllerAdvice
@Order(2)
public class WebAdvice {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebAdvice.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public void handle(RuntimeException e) {
        logger.error("ControllerAdvice is now logged");
    }
}
```

And the result is:

> WebAdvice handle is now logged
>   WebInterceptor after completion is now logged

You can also have a look to this if you need to log the requests: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging

### Here is what I've found about Order, Aspect and ControllerAdvice

You are right, there is no precedence between an `@ControllerAdvice` and a `@Aspect`, well kind of...

I couldn't find out why (not yet), but when an `@Aspect` in pointing on a `@Controller` method, then the point cut will be executed before the `@ControllerAdvice`, no matter the Order you set

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(1)
public class MyAspect {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAspect.class);

    @After("execution(* WebController.user(..))")
    public void afterLog() {
        logger.error("Aspect is now logged");
    }
}

@RestControllerAdvice
@Order(2)
public class WebAdvice {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebAdvice.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public void handle(RuntimeException e) {
        logger.error("ControllerAdvice is now logged");
    }
}
```

If you `Get http://localhost:8080/user` the result will be :

> Aspect is now logged
>   ControllerAdvice is now logged

But I've found something interesting: If you set a pointcut `@After` the `@ControllerAdvice` then you have the aspect being executed after the controllerAdvice:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(1)
public class MyAspect {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAspect.class);

    @After("execution(* WebAdvice.handle(..)) || execution(* WebController.user(..))")
    public void afterLog() {
        logger.error("Aspect is now logged");
    }
}
```

It is executed 2 times. One after the Controller, and one after the Advice.

> Aspect is now logged
>   ControllerAdvice is now logged
>   Aspect is now logged

Maybe this could fit your needs, but I don't really find this as an elegant solution...

The thing that still need to be solved:

- Finding a way to have a precedence over `Aspect` and `ControllerAdvice`

Hope it helps anyway. If I find something better, I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes putting the controller advice as a pointcut in the logger aspect does make it work, but I don't like this solution either

Comment: What about the interceptor ?

Comment: Did you know that Spring Actuator was based on Interceptor to build the metric `http.server.request` ? Have a look to this class `org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.LongTaskTimingHandlerInterceptor`. Might be helpful for you to see how Spring does that